# Running perl command form shell script

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I have a list of points coordinates in 2 column format first column x-axis, second column y-axis, and I'd like to make a script to rescale the axis.

> **input file example**
> 4 3
> 3 6
>
> **output file example (rescale to 10 10)**
> 10 5
> 7.5 10

To do that, I first get the biggest coordinate on both column (using `sort`, `head` and `cut`), and then I interpolate all lines using a perl substitute regexp.

So I scripted that :

```
#!/bin/sh
# run:  $ ./normalize x y input_file output_file
X=$1
Y=$2
INPUT=$3
OUTPUT=$4

BIGGEST_FIRST_COLUMN=$(sort -nrk1 $INPUT | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
BIGGEST_SECOND_COLUMN=$(sort -nrk2 $INPUT | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

PERL_CMD="'s!([\d.]+)\s([\d.]+)!(\$1/$BIGGEST_FIRST_COLUMN*$X).\" \".(\$2/$BIGGEST_SECOND_COLUMN*$Y)!e'"

CMD="perl -pe $PERL_CMD $INPUT > $OUTPUT"
echo "Run the following cmd : "
echo $CMD

$CMD
```

This code output the perl onliner I want to run and then try to run it.
At this point, the perl oneliner is working : I can copy-paste it and running it by hand and it gives the correct output. Nevertheless, I got a bug when the script run it automatically :

```
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

I suppose this is due to some problem in my comprehension of `"` and `'` in shell, but at this point, I have no idea... So if you have any tips, welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the last line:

```
#!/bin/sh
# run:  $ ./normalize x y input_file output_file
X=$1
Y=$2
INPUT=$3
OUTPUT=$4

BIGGEST_FIRST_COLUMN=$(sort -nrk1 $INPUT | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
BIGGEST_SECOND_COLUMN=$(sort -nrk2 $INPUT | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

PERL_CMD="'s!([\d.]+)\s([\d.]+)!(\$1/$BIGGEST_FIRST_COLUMN*$X).\" \".(\$2/$BIGGEST_SECOND_COLUMN*$Y)!e'"

CMD="perl -pe $PERL_CMD $INPUT > $OUTPUT"
echo "Run the following cmd : "
echo $CMD

# $CMD  < no
eval $CMD
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl one-liner that will do as you ask without needing the shell to preprocess the data

```
perl -MList::Util=max -E'@d=map[split],<>;for $i(0,1){$m=max map $$_[$i],@d; $$_[$i]*=10/$m for @d} say qq{@$_} for @d' data.txt
```

#### output

```
10 5
7.5 10
```

Comment: Ahah, nice ! Not comfortable enough to write one-liner like that yet :-)